# I want a select in mysqsl

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table like this :

```
online_date  online_time  offline_date offline_time
2017-01-29   17:07:07     2017-01-31   17:44:09
```

I Want an output like this :

```
online_date  online_time  offline_date offline_time   difference_in_minute
2017-01-29   17:07:07     2017-01-31   17:44:09         1002
```

how can I have a select that give me difference time between two date time per row ?

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TIMESTAMP(online_date,online_time), TIMESTAMP(offline_date,offline_time))   from table
```

Well, using  [TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp)  function we can add date and time values each other and then using [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) we can calculate differnce between two dates (in `MINUTE` in this case).

Comment: Please include some explanation.

Comment: @mickmackusa - This query is simple and I think it describes itself, though, I added little explanation also.

Comment: Thank you for your good SO citizenship.  Your answer was in the moderation queue for being low-quality.  Always try to explain your code so that readers who are unfamiliar with the given language have a better chance of gaining traction.

Comment: @mickmackusa - Ok, understand, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
SELECT online_date,  online_time,  offline_date, offline_time, (online_time-offline_time) AS difference_in_minute
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: this give me diffrence in minute?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **DATEDIFF**!

```
SELECT online_date,  online_time,  offline_date, offline_time, DATEDIFF(MINUTE,online_time,offline_time) AS difference_in_minute
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```